# Log shipping from SQL Server 2014 Enterprise db to SQL Server 2017 Standard with partitioning

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, log-shipping, standard-edition

I wish to implement log shipping from my current primary which is a SQL Server 2014 Enterprise database to a SQL Server 2017 Standard edition database. I also wish to implement table partitioning on my primary (2014 Enterprise) database. Table partitioning only became available at Standard edition level from SQL Server 2016 Standard SP1 onward.

I believe this will work I need to test it first. My problem is that SQL Server Evaluation edition seems to only correspond to Enterprise/Developer edition or at least that is my understanding. I do not have access to 2017 Standard edition without purchasing but do not want to purchase it without knowing if my proposed log shipping implementation would work for sure.

Has anyone else implemented similar, or does anyone know how to restrict an evaluation edition so that it corresponds to Standard?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that unless you have access to an appropriate MSDN subscription, in which case you can temporarily install the specific edition you need in a test environment. A long time ago I argued for an eval edition that could act like any specific edition, but Microsoft wasn't buying into it. But also consider your alternatives: if this doesn't work, what are you going to do? Buy Enterprise anyway? Stick with 2014? Not use log shipping?

Comment: You could try this out very easily and pretty cheaply by signing up for a cloud hosting provider and spinning up a small Standard Edition VM to test it out on.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. I will explore both suggestions on the MSDN subscription and the cloud implementation. In answer to the question on alternatives, we will probably go with Log shipping on a 2014 Standard instance for the medium term but there is a longer term issue of archiving old data on an increasingly busy set of tables for which partitioning would be appropriate solution. Price point is tying my hands in terms of Enterprise licensing unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe this will work I need to test it first. My problem is that SQL Server Evaluation edition seems to only correspond to Enterprise/Developer edition or at least that is my understanding. I do not have access to 2017 Standard edition without purchasing but do not want to purchase it without knowing if my proposed log shipping implementation would work for sure.

According to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017), Express Edition can also handle table partitioning in 2016 SP1+. Thus you could setup an extremely small database, create a new partitioned table, and log ship it from 2014 Enterprise Edition to 2017 Express Edition and see if it works. Express edition is free and can be [easily downloaded](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) and installed.

If it works, then it'll work in Standard. If it doesn't, then it won't work in standard and it has some but not all feature parity across editions in 2016 SP1+ with partitioning being one of those that is available across all editions.